# FairPlayKeyData apple activation

Tags: certificate, drm, activation

has anybody seen something like that?

```
-----BEGIN CONTAINER-----
AAEAAbhNth6wR78Jv94ci38B8XFG0Q1xdb2+JXji2RATYKGibZb41Syi1j/gB7oH
62qFCGdG2cFPm8Kj5eDDb6lpqW3WKmTPhMZE2aa/GCClgOPNu/Qqfb2vqWAwvgHy
.........
3jGzdXy6d4h7yfhycVcM2OtoE0eM701TpxWSPyjPawe6VKndfNN8C881iwiABFfN
qCtsUB+OxDDeJndc3VVxMEEPC2JujTbElPi/ekt1Xr2gHYLa
-----END CONTAINER-----
```

what does this container means? how it is generated?
iTunes send to apple FairPlayCertChain certificate and FairPlaySignature, apple responds with FairPlayKeyData and other info...

Comment: Have you discovered something new ? I am also looking into activation process.

Answer (score 2):

An introduction to Fairplay DRM can be found on page 2 of
http://teal.gmu.edu/courses/ECE646/project/reports_2007/AD-1.pdf

More about White-Box DES (what's behind the DRM) and one implementation of generating such containers:
https://crypto.stanford.edu/DRM2002/whitebox.pdf

Abstract of the second PDF:

> For applications such as digital rights management (drm) solutions employing cryptographic implementations in software, white-box cryptography (or more formally: a cryptographic implementation designed to withstand the white-box attack context) is more appropriate
>   than traditional
>   black-box
>   cryptography. In the white-box context, the
>   attacker has total visibility into software implementation and execution,
>   and our objective is to prevent the extraction of secret keys from the
>   program. We present methods to make key extraction difficult in the
>   white-box context, with focus on symmetric block ciphers implemented
>   by substitution boxes and linear transformations. A
>   des
>   implementation
>   (useful also for triple-
>   des
>   ) is presented as a concrete example.

If such information is not what you're looking for, please be more thorough in your question.

Comment: That's DRM in general, but what concrete format is used in the aforementioned snippet ?

Comment: First paragraph of first link: "We cite failures of WMDRM and Fairplay DRM to highlight
those weaknesses." Although it's mostly about general DRM, it highlights FairPlay DRM in how it's supposed to work and how it fails.